# A hundred contexts vs one context in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas

I'm creating a simple physics engine working with the Canvas API. What is the best practice in terms of performance? Is it to create a separate context for ever object in the canvas (ex. for every ball, box etc..), or to use just one context? The latter involves defining the path on the context for every object to be redrawn, plus setting the color etc..

Is it a bad idea to use multiple contexts when the number of objects get near a hundred?

The reason why I ask, is because I don't want to get a surprise a hundred working hours later because I went with the wrong way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Performance gains with multiple canvas’s comes from knowing *why* you use multiple canvases.**

Don’t use multiple canvases unless they serve a useful purpose:

- Canvases are modestly expensive elements.
- On mobile, canvases are still quite slow—-multiple canvases are slower.

Here are some reasons to use more than 1 canvas:

**You have drawings that animate at different times.**

For example, a background might animate every 5 frames while your more active objects might animate every frame.  Having the background on a second canvas means you don’t have to draw the background every animation frame.

**You want to “double buffer” to increase display speed.**

For example, while the current frame is being displayed, you might use a second canvas to assemble a complex element and then use displayContext.drawImage(bufferCanvas,0,0) to draw the buffer canvas on the display canvas.  This lets you use the “downtime” between animation frames to ready your next frame.

**You use canvas to make variations on a single image/drawnElement (templating).**

For example, if you need a physical barrier (say an image of a gray building).  You might desire red, blue and green buildings for variety.  You could have the gray building image on an offscreen canvas and use context’s globalCompositeOperation to recolor that one building into red,blue and green variations. This lets you reuse 1 image resource in multiple ways.

There are other reasons for multiple canvases, but the point is to use multiple canvases to fill a need.

Comment: The question is about multiple contexts per canvas, not about multiple canvases.

Comment: Thanks @JanDvorak...OOPS, I see that now.  Still, I'll leave my answer here as some of the reasons for using multiple canvases apply to using multiple contexts too.

Comment: "Each context is supported by a pixel array that is fully the size of its canvas" -- I would think that all 2D contexts are backed by the same buffer. Why it isn't so?

Comment: @JanDvorak: You know…I think you’re right about the backing buffer being the same.  For example,  ctx1.rect(50,50,10,10)  then ctx2.fillRect(10,10,10,10)  will draw a ctx2’s rect at [10,10].  A subsequent ctx1.fillRect(100,100,10,10) will draw ctx1’s rect at [100,100] but not [50,50].  And then a further ctx1.stroke() will draw the ctx1’s rect at [50,50].  This leads me to think contexts will accumulate drawing commands rather than drawing to a separate buffer.  So if any context "buffers" it's next commands, can you envision any reasons to have many contexts on a single canvas?

Comment: Each context has its own stroke, fill, clip, set of transformations and possibly other attributes. It helps if you don't have to set these values as the browser has to parse a hex string each time you set a fill or stroke color.

Comment: Okay, I'll add a update. The reason why I asked this question was as @JanDvorak said, you can have one context per object, so you don't have to redefine all the style and position properties for each frame in the animation. Problem is this is true: `canvas.getContext('2d') == canvas.getContext('2d')`, because JS is supplying you with the same object each time. I think there is a way to get different ones by specifiying a different ID, but I haven't found how... Maybe that's an indicator the canvas is optimized for only one context..?

Comment: +1 for supplying me with some useful information anyway. Since you wrote an answer this thorough, I think it's worth a +1 even though it's not a correct answer!

Comment: @FriendofKim chances are that if `canvas.getContext("2d")` caches its return value, you won't be able to get a second context...

Comment: would it make sense to do double buffering by actually swapping (with z-indexes) the two canvases, rather than blitting one into the other?

Comment: you can always save things that will not change (background or fixed elements) to a variable and then paint the rest.
In next frame, instead painting everything from the beginning, you can just draw what is stored in a variable.
I dint test it but I think it might be fast.